# Returning Values to Spreadsheet Dialogue Box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Goal:**

Return data from an App Script function into a custom Spreadsheet HTML Form.

**Issue:**

Script returns "Undefined"

**Apps Script:**

```
function displaySSUI(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index.html").evaluate();
  ss.show(html);
  return
}

function returnVal () {
   Logger.log("So far so good")            // Displays in Apps Script Logger
   return "Good"
}
```

**Script inside Spreadsheet HTML Dialogue:**

```
<script>
   var str = google.script.run.returnVal()
   alert(str);                             // Alert box says undefined
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `google.script.run` will run asynchronously, it cannot return a value immediately. This is why `str` is undefined.

You need to create a callback function to access the returned value:

```
<script>
  //function to be called when .returnVal() returns
  var onSuccess = function(str) {
    alert(str);
  }

  //use .withSuccessHandler() to set the callback function
  var str = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).returnVal()
</script>
```